# Spring Boot MongoDB return only greater dates, but not equal dates with different time

Tags: spring, mongodb, rest, spring-boot

I am making REST service with Spring Boot and MongoDB.

I have MongoDB with field 'startDate' that has values in long format (ex. 1484766055120).

I converted it in Spring Boot to readable format (property Sample.class):

```
@Field(targetType = FieldType.INT64)
private java.util.Date startDate;
```

I am making some search based on date:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dd-MM-yyyy);
Date date = (Date) formatter.parse(startDateParam);
query = new Query(Criteria.where("startDate").gt(date));
// I also have new Query(Criteria.where("startDate").is(date)) situation; 
return mongoTemplate.find(query, Sample.class);
```

When I pass 27-01-2017 as startDateParam I have problem that REST returns for example entry with value 2017-01-27T12:52:53.482+0000 (because is greater than 2017-01-27T00:00:00.000+0000)...

How not to return that value, but only grater dates?

Comment: Technically the output is correct. However if you want to get data from 28-01-2017 you can increment the date before setting it in Criteria. As per my limited knowledge, mongo db does not have a trunc(date) function similar to oracle else that could be one other option.

Comment: @DhavalShewale thank you for your answer, I agree correct values are returned, but I have specific case where I need to ignore time in date value...

Comment: @DhavalShewale your solution will work for gt and lt queries, but what for is(date)?

Comment: Well in that case you might have to use greater than equal to `date` and less than `date+1`. Though I don't think this is a good approach but should meet your needs. Any specific reason you can't store date without the timestamp? That would be an ideal way to store data if your use case always demands to ignore timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

As you are still using `Date` data types and want to find the next dates, ignoring all of the intermediate dateTime values. Though those methods are depricated, you can try this.

```
...
Date date_gt = (Date) formatter.parse(startDateParam);

// manually bypass all the values.
date_gt.setHours(23);
date_gt.setMinutes(59);
date_gt.setSeconds(59);

query = new Query(Criteria.where("startDate").gt(date_gt));
return mongoTemplate.find(query, Sample.class);
...

// and for exact match
Date date = (Date) formatter.parse(startDateParam);
query = new Query(Criteria.where("startDate").is(date)); 
return mongoTemplate.find(query, Sample.class);
```

Hope this workaround could help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't know values of properties I need to set, I will get them when I do mongoTemplate.find(..)
I can do filtering after I get that list, but that isn't great option for me...

Comment: well this workaround could get you the next date. What you are looking for.

Comment: Thats a new things. Can you please elaborate what does `is(date)` do? expected input output?

Comment: Returns true for same date (with time). But i can use gt that date and lt next day for that, I guess...

Comment: as you know the exact functionality. then you can use two different variable like: date_grater(which has custom minute/hour/second set) for and date_exact(equals to original date).